# Any way to list request header names with JSF EL -- without backing bean?

Tags: jsf, el

Is there any way to use JSF EL (Java EE 7) to list all the request's header names and corresponding values in a 2-column table, without introducing a backing bean? I can do it if I create a bean and access that from EL, so I do have a means to the end -- but the thing I'm trying to figure out is  if it can be done entirely with "out of the box" EL.  "That's not possible" would be a fine answer -- I'm still learning.

I thought something like this:

```
  <table>
    <ui:repeat value="#{request.getHeaderNames()}" var="hdr">
      <tr>
        <td>#{hdr}</td>
        <td>#{headerValues[hdr]}</td>
      </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
  </table>
```

But that gives a 1-row table, something like this:

```
org.apache.catalina.util.Enumerator@2dbf763b    [Ljava.lang.String;@74eb32f3
```

I suspect that because `request.getHeaderNames()` is giving an enumerator instead of a list of some kind that `ui:repeat` wants, this approach won't work at all, and I need to do something fundamentally different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just iterate over `#{headerValues}` itself. You only need either JSTL `<c:forEach>`,

```
<dl>
    <c:forEach items="#{headerValues}" var="entry">
        <dt>#{entry.key}</dt>
        <c:forEach items="#{entry.value}" var="headerValue">
            <dd>#{headerValue}</dd>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
</dl>
```

or to make use of EL 2.2 feature to convert `Map` to `Entry[]` as follows, as `<ui:repeat>` doesn't support maps but only lists and arrays:

```
<dl>
    <ui:repeat value="#{headerValues.entrySet().toArray()}" var="entry">
        <dt>#{entry.key}</dt>
        <ui:repeat value="#{entry.value}" var="headerValue">
            <dd>#{headerValue}</dd>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ui:repeat>
</dl>
```

Note that each value of `#{headerValues}` represents a `String[]`, so I've fixed that for you as well, with a proper data structure.

Comment: Thanks!  The first example works fine, but the second example throws a 500 - Internal Server Error in GlassFish 4.0:  `javax.servlet.ServletException: Class javax.el.ELUtil can not access a member of class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap with modifiers "public"` which I believe is from `#{headerValues.entrySet().toArray()}` -- any thoughts on that?

Comment: Reproduced. Also in GF 3.1.2.2. IMO a bug in GF's EL implementation. Works fine in Apache's one (Tomcat, JBoss, WebSphere, etc). Anyway, just stick to `<c:forEach>`. It doesn't harm as long as you don't hit a view scoped bean property in Mojarra versions older than 2.1.18.